# Остаток времени до определенного момента

Tags: java, android

Здравствуйте, помогите пожалуйста как реализовать. Допустим у меня записано время 14:00 и в соответствии с реальным времени писалось сколько до этого времени остаётся это можно как-нибудь сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> это можно как-нибудь сделать?

Можно!

```
Date deadlineDate = dateFormatUCT.parse(deadline);

if(currentDate.after(deadlineDate)) {
    // что нужно сделать если время уже наступило
}

long timeDiff = currentDate.getTime() - deadlineDate.getTime();
```

и делаешь с timeDiff что нужно.

Другие реализации можно найти с помощью поиска по "remaining time java"

Comment: Нужна помощь с реализации)))

Comment: Как сформулирован вопрос, таков и ответ. Вопрос был про можно ли :)

Comment: Буду пробовать)

Comment: Попробовал, не работает, Выделяет красным date, dateFormatUCT, deadline, currentDate,

Comment: Подключи соответствующие зависимости от внутренних библиотек. Зависимости найдешь нужные в гугле :) А то я не джавист потому с ходу не скажу.... И нету разницы кто из нас их будет гуглить :)